# How to deploy my Laravel React project in production status

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I currently now deploying my project to our server, before i do the deployment I have step to do before i send it to our server.

1. First on my cmd I type npm install composer.
2. Second on my cmd I type npm run production.
3. Third i check first my project to determine if the status of production of react logo on the top of browser turning to blue in which finally my project now on production.
   [image: running on localhost]
4. Finally I zip my files and send it to the server.

Those are the scenario that I do before I deploy my project in production mode.
however in my case I have problem when i browse my application URL. ex. www.mylaravelreact.com the directory of my files is shown to my application.

I read some question regarding problem about why does my site say index of and list my files https://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/website/website-help/why-does-my-site-say-index-of-and-list-my-files

**In my Root Folder i have server.php**

[image: server.php]

**In my Public Folder i have index.php**

[image: index.php]

**Why does my site look this when i open it.**

[image: Production]

Comment: there is no index.html or index.htm in your  second screenshot. Maybe the wrong directory path in your server config. If you use nginx, plz show the config file.

Comment: @Robin hi robin. sorry for that, where the index.html place in the project? actually this project is newly download from laravel documentation.

Comment: You should point your root server location onto `public` directory. Anything else is not secure.

Comment: I have project created in laravel when i try to deploy it works. however when i deploy this project it look like that.